# Garbled or error when using print() function with UTF-8 CJK characters in Python on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, cjk

I had a source with UTF-8 encoding:(name.py)

```py
print("请您输入您的名字:")
input()
```

And run it on Windows 7:(Region: China, Language: Simplified Chinese)

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>py -3 name.py
璇锋偍杈撳叆鎮ㄧ殑鍚嶅瓧:
foo
C:\Users\User\Desktop>chcp 65001
C:\Users\User\Desktop>py -3 name.py
??????????????????????????????:
foo
```

And run it on Windows 10:(Region: China, Language: Simplified Chinese)

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>py -3 name.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "name.py", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\u7487' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
C:\Users\User\Desktop>chcp 65001
C:\Users\User\Desktop>py -3 name.py
??????????????????????????????:
foo
```

But is is normal on Linux:

```sh
$ python3 name.py
请您输入您的名字:
foo
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Windows 10. Check your console settings or better yet, use Windows Terminal instead of Console. Maybe even upgrade Windows 10 to a supported version. `?` is how *non*-Unicode applications display characters without a match in their codepage. Windows is a natively Unicode OS, unlike Linux and applications compiled for Unicode haven't had any problems since 2000 when Windows 2000 started replacing the DOS-based Windows 9x line. The console *behaved* like a non-Unicode application up until recently because frankly people had abandoned console applications by 2000.

Comment: 3 years ago the console subsystem was revamped and Windows Terminal was created. [This series of articles explains how things were before and how they changed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/). Windows 10 1809 is out of support by now. In any case, in the *old* console *application* you had to enable UTF8 in the console settings, not by changing the codepage

Comment: "*Windows is a natively Unicode OS*" is misleading. Yes, Windows internally is all Unicode, but Unicode is not a first citizen in Windows. Most Windows applications are not using Unicode by default. Linux (and Unix) are interesting because kernel has no Unicode support (strings are just strings), but all programs works with unicode natively (also if they were not programmed for unicode). Different kind of Unicode support (or lack of it). But it is just Windows which still do not consider Unicode as first class citizen.